# Change VS Code debug console font color?

Tags: spring, debugging, visual-studio-code, colors

For whatever reason, the font color of my debug console is a blue which makes it really difficult to read. I'm not sure if this is due to vs code settings or maybe project settings as, when I put a break point and evaluate expressions, the font color is a readable white. How can I change this output color to something more legible? See image below:

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to change your setting in VS Code's setting.json. The required property is

```
{
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": 
    {
        "debugConsole.infoForeground": "#ffffff"
    }
}
```

This setting will change the color to white. You can of course change it to any other color you would like to.

There are other properties as well, like `debugConsole.errorForeground`, `debugConsole.warningForeground`, etc. which you might want to change as well. All of these properties are inside `workbench.colorCustomization`

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much.

Comment: @Isaac Glad to help! Please mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to make use of full colour log output in the 'Debug Console' window then add the following property to your debugging spring profile:

```
spring.output.ansi.enabled=always
```

Alternatively, add it to your debug configuration `vmArgs`:

```
"vmArgs": [
  "-Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always"
]
```